# Jointure between 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

Here is my 4 tables :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Personne (
    id serial,
    nom varchar(30),
    prenom varchar(30)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Commune (
    id serial,
    nom varchar(30),
    nbr_clients INT DEFAULT 0
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Staff_admin (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Personne(id)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Client (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ref_commune BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ref_staff_admin BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Personne(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (ref_commune) REFERENCES Commune(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (ref_staff_admin) REFERENCES Staff_admin(id)
)
```

So when I select a Client I need to get:

Client Name, Commune name, Staff_admin Name.

Comment: Is `jointure` an actual term you heard being used by someone?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Trivial query. Did you try anything before asking?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need a table with only one field to map the staff admin role. Add a field in the table you really need it (maybe Client?). Anyway, the join query you need could be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Client c, Commune cc, Staff_admin sa, Personne p
WHERE c.ref_commune  = cc.id AND c.ref_staff_admin = sa.id AND sa.id = p.id
```

Comment: @BOUHOUALID (I wouldn't boast about it ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

You need a join for every table you want to retrieve data from:

```
SELECT p.nom, co.nom, sap.nom
FROM   client cl
JOIN   personne p ON p.id = cl.id
JOIN   commune co ON p.ref_commune = co.id
JOIN   personne sap ON sap.id = cl.ref_staff_admin
```